# java regex capture group

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to capture the right part after the : using java expr, but in the following code, the printed capture group is the whole string, what's wrong?

```
String s ="xyz: 123a-45";   
String patternStr="xyz:[ \\t]*([\\S ]+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
//System.err.println(s);
if(m.find()){
    int count = m.groupCount();
    System.out.println("group count is "+count);
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        System.out.println(m.group(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Numbering of subgroups starts with 1, 0 is the full text. Just go till count+1 with your loop.

Comment: More precisely, change the `for` loop condition to `i<=count`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because group's indices are starting with 1. Group 0 is the entire pattern.

From the JavaDoc: "Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one. Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is equivalent to m.group()."
See more [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29)

Comment: I think the confusion over this stems from the fact that the doc has muddled "indexing" (always from 0) with "numbering" (from whatever value you like).