# Negate a regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need some help find a regular expression matching of a text sting for every char expect the first 10.
For example, I used the regex:

.{10}              to match the first 10 chars of the text

P53236TT0834691

**P53236TT08** 34691    --> matching

But I need the negative result as matching (from char 11 to x )
Can someone help me with the right expression?

Answer (score 3):

Use a lookbehind:

```
(?<=^.{10}).*
```

This will ensure that there are 10 characters before the start of the match and then will match anything until the end of the string.

Comment: As a side-note, I think the caret is unnecessary, but as it doesn't matter that much anyway...

Comment: I included it because it makes intent clearer, but yes, it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: No idea.  I upvoted to counter it since I profiled it and it's consistently faster.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, you can use:

```
String pattern = ".{10}(.*)";
```

The first capturing group will capture all characters in your search string past the 10th.  You can trivially extend this to skip any number of characters.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to match and extract what you need, so the regex would be something like so: `^.{10}(.*)$`. This will throw any text coming after the 10th character in a group which you can then access later, as illustrated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865377/java-regex-capture-group) previous SO question.