# Find which part of a regular expression caused a match

Tags: java, regex

I've got a regular expression of the following format:

```
((.*)Venue1(.*)) | ((.*)Venue2(.*)) | ((.*)Venue3(.*))
```

Then I've got some twitter messages and using this regular expression I'm finding if a venue is mentioned in the messages (I know that this method has some bugs, but at the moment is fine for me). However in that way I don't know which exactly venue was mentioned, because I'm using `tweet.matches(regex)`. I was thinking to break the whole regex and check the twitter message against each venue name separately. Do you think there is a faster way to check, which venue namer from the long regex, caused the match?

Comment: Why don't you loop and check `.contains(venueName)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place all venues within a single group and get that group's value:

```
.*(Venue1|Venue2|Venue3).*
```

In the regex above, the **matched venue would be group one**. (I'm assuming your venues are just examples, if they aren't you could simplify further `.*(Venue[123]).*`.)

After that, you can use [`Matcher#group(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    checkVenue("Test Venue1 test test");
    checkVenue("Test Venue2 test test");
    checkVenue("Test Venue3 test test");
    checkVenue("Test Venue1 Venue3 test");
}

public static void checkVenue(String tweet) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(Venue1|Venue2|Venue3).*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(tweet);
    System.out.print(tweet + ":\t ");
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("found " + m.group(1));
    } else {
        System.out.println("found none.");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Test Venue1 test test:   found Venue1
Test Venue2 test test:   found Venue2
Test Venue3 test test:   found Venue3
Test Venue1 Venue3 test:     found Venue3
```

**[Run this demo online here](http://ideone.com/LpE5NH)**.

Comment: Great! That helps me a lot : )

Answer (score 2):

Use `(.*)Venue([123])(.*)`, then check what's between the 2nd pair of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You could use groups. Something along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865377/java-regex-capture-group) may solve tour problem. [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#regex_grouping) also has some examples. Googling "java regex group" will give you quite a lot of references :)