# RegEx How to get everything after a /

Tags: java, regex

I'm currently using http://www.regexr.com/ and the Strings I'm trying to parse through are in the format of `133a1d6a-f4fa-49ba-928d-0f4c943ce5d3/File-20140805-013806693.pdf`.

I'm trying to get only the portion after the `/` and before `.pdf`.

My current regex pattern I have is:
`/\/([A-Za-z0-9-])+/g`

which gives me: `/File-20140805-013806693`

How do I make the pattern omit the `/` AND the `file type` only matching `File-20140805-013806693`

My next step is to put this into java code while iterating through a loop of these Strings.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just access the capture group.

Comment: Instead of regexr you should use a tool which knows Java's regex syntax. You can also use Eclipse's Search with a similar effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
(?<=\/)[A-Za-z0-9-]+
```

Comment: I removed the grouping parentheses, I used them as snapshot from your solution, I just added the part to exclude the forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be what you are looking for.

```
.*\/([^./]+).[\w\d]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ATGSq9SZbx9udT3j)

This regex gets all the file extensions if you just want `.pdf` do this.

```
.*\/([^./]+).pdf$
```

Comment: Nice, this works in javascript but realized that the tool I was using would not work with java. Any idea how it would convert to java?

Comment: @Richard Look at this post on how to compile and use capture groups with java. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865377/java-regex-capture-group Rember index 0 captures the entire stirng in the capture statement. So in this case the captured group that you would want would be at `group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of lookahead and lookbehind:

```
/(?<=\/).*?(?=\.pdf)/g
```

You can test it [here](http://regex101.com/r/cM8mI4/2).

Comment: Thanks, but this match still includes the file type.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part, now it's fixed